# Plane integral for continuous curves

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-topology, plane-curves

I'm trying to understand complex path integral $\int_C f(z)dz$ for continuous closed curve $C$.

1. Is it necessary that $C$ is rectifiable and not just generally continuous?
2. Do we get all the topological results with rectifiable curves? Like winding number for continuous and closed curves, and from that Brouwer fixed point theorem.

So what are the conditions when we move from continuously differentiable curves to continuous curves in integral?

Comment: For holomorphic $f$, you can define $\int_C f(z)\,dz$ for an arbitrary continuous curve by approximating $C$ with rectifiable (or even piecewise smooth) curves. Cauchy's integral theorem asserts that the value doesn't depend on the chosen approximation, as long as it's good enough. For non-holomorphic $f$, I don't think you can go past rectifiable curves.

Comment: Thanks for answering. And I indeed ment holomorphic functions.